# Is this expression always irrational?

Tags: nt.number-theory, gm.general-mathematics

Is it right that

**$$\sqrt[a]{2^{2^n}+1}$$**

for every $$a>1,n \in \mathbb N $$

is always irrational?

Comment: This question was simultaneously posted to MSE.

Comment: yes but nobody got an accurate answer. Nobody told me if its always irrational or not. Thats why im asking here

Comment: When you cross post, you should say so in your post. You also posted the question to MSE only one hour ago - you might get a useful answer there soon.

Comment: OK! But what do you guess? Are there a>1,n so it's rational?

Comment: You have been given a clear answer by MSE user @lhf prior to asking here. This is a bit of abuse.

Comment: But isn't squarefreness stronger than this irrationality? I mean 63 isn't squarefree but for every root its irrational, isnt it?

Comment: For some real a the result is rational. For integer a you should be able to show it is not rational by elementary means.  Gerhard "Leaves The Proof To You" Paseman, 2018.05.24.

Comment: Everyone knows this was posted to mse, but no one is providing the link?

Comment: I used the user name link. By the way, a short argument using gcd shows a must be even.  Gerhard "And What Is Your Argument?" Paseman, 2018.05.24.

Comment: Must be even for irrationality?

Comment: Cross-posted here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2794715/is-this-expression-always-irrational/2794958#2794958

Answer (score 5):

Here is a slick example that uses just parity after some basic results.

For the radical expression to be rational, either it is an integer or a is irrational.  Ruling out the latter case, rewrite as $2^{2^n}= (b-1)[(b^a-1)/(b-1)]$. $b$ cannot be 2 as we get even on the left hand side and right on the odd hand side, so b is odd and the square bracket term is the sum of a many odd numbers, so a must be even.

But the expression under the radical is one more than a perfect square, and 1 is the only positive integer which is square and one more than a perfect square. So b=1, and n must be negative infinity.

Gerhard "Did You See That Coming?" Paseman, 2018.05.24.

Comment: Since im german i dont really understand the argumentation, is it for a odd, even or for all? What does it exsctly prove lol

Comment: The first part uses parity to show that if there is an integral solution, then a is even.  The second part shows that there are no solutions when a is even. The last phrase is a joke, as it references a value of n that makes 2^2^n zero.  There is no negative integer n that does that, so I have to look to n being an uncountable infinity. Gerhard "Think Really, Really, Really Small" Paseman, 2018.05.24.

Comment: So you proved all even roots^^ (i dont even know yet if your proof is true - late here maybe ill see tommorrow xD). But in those cases always consider using the binominal formula a^2-b^2=(a+b)*(a-b) very helpfull and easy solution

Answer (score 4):

If $a$ is meant to be an integer then $x^a-2^{2^n}=1$ for some integer $x$. This contradicts Catalan's conjecture, proved by Preda Mihăilescu. Actually, the special case $x^a-2^b=1$, where $a,b>1$, was first solved by Lebesgue, the only solution being $3^2-2^3=1$.