# Solution to an exponential Diophantine equation

Tags: nt.number-theory, diophantine-equations

I am trying to solve the following exponential Diophantine equation:

$$ 9^{k_1} -2^{j_1} = 9^{k_2}-2^{j_2}$$

My conjecture is that this implies $k_1=k_2$ and $j_1=j_2$, apart from eventually some small few exceptions. Is this true?

Comment: One can move all the $2'$s to the same side and $9'$s to the other side, then apply LTE lemma after a few consideration modulo 9 and 2. One obtain very "unbalanced" inequalities which are very unlikely to be satisfied for big variables $k_1, k_1-k_2, j_1, j_1-j_2$, but I can't getn explicit bound.

Comment: A similar question https://mathoverflow.net/a/301089 has been recently answered by Richard Stanley which answers this question.  Gerhard "It's Almost A Duplicate Question" Paseman, 2018.05.27.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman hm, how does it reduce to Catalan conjecture?

Comment: @Fedor, It doesn't. It breaks into two pieces, one of them being 3^2a - 1 = 2^b, which is addressed by Richard's answer. The other piece is 2^a - 1 = 3^2b, which I believe can be resolved by elementary methods not distant from Richard's answer.  Gerhard "So Maybe Half A Duplicate" Paseman, 2018.05.27.

Comment: I calculate that the exceptional solution has both sides equal -7.  Gerhard "Is Quite Fond Of Sevens" Paseman, 2018.05.27.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman how does it break? I do not understand.

Comment: @Fedor, you write it in the form 9^a(9^b-1)=2^c(2^d-1) and consider odd and even parts.  I am surprised, but happy to explain further.  Gerhard "Really Thought It Wasn't Needed" Paseman, 2018.05.27.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, this follows from a conjecture of Pillai (1945), which was proved by Stroeker and Tijdeman (1982). For references and generalizations see:

M. A. Bennett, Pillai’s conjecture revisited, J. Number Theory 98 (2003), 228-235.

R. Scott, R. Styer, On $p^x-q^y=c$ and related three term exponential Diophantine equations with prime bases, J. Number Theory 105 (2004), 212-234.

Comment: Would you be so kind as to provide the statement of Pillai's conjecture?  Gerhard "Curious Students Wish To Know" Paseman, 2018.05.27.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: The conjecture says that an integer $c$ can be expressed in at most one way as $3^x-2^y$ except when $c\in\{1,-5,-13\}$. In the latter case, there are two representations: $3-2=3^2-2^3=1$, $3-2^3=3^3-2^5=-5$, $3-2^4=3^5-2^8=-13$.

Comment: Are x and y nonzero? Otherwise we have -7= 1-8=9-16.  Gerhard "Thank You For The Statement" Paseman, 2018.05.27.

Comment: I assumed that the exponents are positive integers (as do all the sources I know). I guess, but I am not sure, that case of exponent zero can be treated similarly. BTW Bennett (2001) also showed that $a^x-b^y=c$ always has at most two solutions (with fixed $a,b\geq 2$, fixed $c\neq 0$, and variable $x,y\geq 1$), and he classified the cases when there are two.